# Include .dll of different version than project targets

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET application targeting .NET 3.5 and I want to include a .dll in the `bin` directory that was built on .NET 4.5. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use COM Interop to build a bridge layer.

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 namespace Net4ToNet2Adapter
 {
     [ComVisible(true)]
     [Guid("E36BBF07-591E-4959-97AE-D439CBA392FB")]
     public interface IMyClassAdapter
     {
         void DoNet4Action();
     }
 }
```

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204406/How-To-Use-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-From-NET-2-Based-Appl) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now, hypothetically speaking, if I build an ASP.NET application targeting .NET 4 and want to include a .dll built on .NET 4.5 that wouldn't be a problem in that case? Or the inverse case, when I target .NET 4 and use a .dll built on .NET 3.5?

Comment: The inverse case is already compatible. I don't know about .NET 4.5; .NET 3.5 is based on the .NET 2 CLR, whereas .NET4 and .NET4.5 are both based on the .NET 4 CLR.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx